# Client request to server

Tags: javascript, node.js

Client function is requesting for data from Server. I imported this function in other file where I need it to use. It is working fine. But i don't understand why I am receiving on command prompt "Undefined". I have commented all console.log but still it is coming. I'm not sure if export/import has problem?

Here is my code:

// tstReq.js

```
function getData(iccid) {
toString(iccid);
var http = require('http');
var jasParseData;

var options = {
    host: 'demo8620001.mockable.io',
    port: 80,
    path: '/Api3',
    method: 'get'
  };

  http.request(options, function(res) {
    //console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    //console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      //console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
      josParseData= JSON.parse(chunk);
      for(i = 0, len = Object.keys(josParseData.iccid[i]).length; i<=len; i++) {
        //console.log('JSON.parse:',josParseData.iccid[i]);
        //console.log("iccid:     ",iccid);
        if (josParseData.iccid[i] === iccid) {    // Only printed match iccid
          console.log('JSON.parse:',josParseData.iccid[i]);
          console.log("iccid:     ",iccid);
        }
        if (josParseData.iccid[i] === iccid) {
          console.log("Valid Jasper", i+1);
          console.log('\n');
        }
        else{
          // console.log ("Invlid Jasper");
        }
        //console.log('\n');
      }

      //console.log('\n');



    });
  }).end();

};

module.exports = getData;
```

Here is code where I am using exported function:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var validateICCID = require('./funcValidateId.js');
var getData = require('./tstReq.js');

fs.createReadStream('iccid2.csv')
.pipe(parse({delimiter: ':'}))
.on('data',function(csv) {
    csvrow= csv.toString();
    console.log('\n');
    console.log(getData(csvrow));
    console.log('\n');

});
```

Comment: @Barbar this question is too broad and, as it stands, it is also without a clear problem statement. This question will be closed if you do not make changes soon.

Comment: Are you calling that function from the console? If so, then `undefined` is the result of the function work. Also, there is a link on the output where you can see from which place it returned that `Undefined` (in case this is not the return value of the function).

Comment: I have removed function from console.log but I am still have same problem. I just noticed that as I am reading csv file containing 7 iccid numbers so it printed 7 times "Undefined".

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting undefined because the function getData doesn't have a return statement. It doesn't mean your function is broken, it's just not directly returning a result.

If you want to log the result of getData, you'll need to return http.request, and you'll need to resolve the http.request by returning in the callback.

Also, I noticed you declared `var jasParseData` you probably meant josParseData.

Comment: I have replaced jasParseData with josParseData and I added "return 0" in function   but still have same problem about "Undefined".